# Rails routes to show action on custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree, rails-routing

I am trying to add a customer action to one of my resources, therefore I created a custom route:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :subscriptions

  match 'subscriptions/summary', :to => 'subscriptions#summary', :as => 'subscriptions_summary'

end
```

In my **rake routes** I'm getting the following output:

```
admin_subscriptions_summary        /admin/subscriptions/summary(.:format)                               spree/admin/subscriptions#summary
```

The problem now is, whenever I try to create a link to the summary action, I get following error:

```
Missing template spree/admin/subscriptions/show
```

Why is my app confusing the show action with the summary action?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :subscriptions do
    collection do 
      get 'summary'
    end
  end
end
```

solved it.